# ¿Cómo manejar ventanas secundarias con POO y tkinter?

Tags: python, poo, tkinter

Estoy usando POO y tkinter;  y en cada clase estoy creando una nueva ventana. y cada vez que invoco a una clase una nueva ventana se debe crear. el problema es que cuando hago correr el programa, la ventana principal se sobrepone a la secundaria impidiendo que la ventana secundaria (claseA o claseB) complete los procesos que coloque por que cada una tiene sus métodos propios. Porfavor necesito ayuda.

```py
  class claseA:
        def __init__(self):
        self.ventanai=tk.Tk()
        #self.ventanai = window
        self.ventanai.title('A')
        
  class claseB:
        def __init__(self):
        self.ventanai=tk.Tk()
        #self.ventanai = window
        self.ventanai.title('B')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
         boton = tk.Button(ventana, image=imglogo, text="Imagen: jpg, png", compound="top",command=claseA)
    boton.place(x=50,y=60)
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a OOP en lugar de POO? POO significa programación orientada a objetos

Comment: También corrija la sangría. ¿por qué estás tratando de crear un objeto cuando se presiona el botón? Ese objeto se desecha. ¿Ha mirado algún OOP/`tkinter` tutoriales?

Comment: No utilices `Tk` para crear ventanas secundarias. En su lugar utiliza `Toplevel`.